# Unable to retrieve object from mongodb to parent function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to access the object which I got from **mongo collection** to outside its function.

Here's what I am doing:

```
function getOldMessage(user) {
//this is where i want to store the object
var oldMsg = {};
messagedb.findOne({ "room": user.room }, function(err, foundMsg) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        //here i am assigning this foundMsg to my object
        oldMsg = foundMsg;
    }
})
// here this is undefined or an empty object
console.log(oldMsg);
return oldMsg;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var oldMsg` is declared within the scope of getOldMessage and is not accessible in it's parent scope, which is where you're trying to access it. For more information on scope, see [Understanding Scope in JavaScript](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript).

Mongoose methods return promises, so you can use async/await to retrieve the old value from mongo.

```js
const getOldMessage = async user => messagedb.findOne({ "room": user.room });

const oldMessage = await getOldMessage(someUser);
console.log(oldMessage);
```

Or if you prefer `Promise`

```js
const getOldMessage = user => new Promise((resolve, reject) =>  
    messagedb.findOne({ "room": user.room },(err, foundMsg) => {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        resolve(foundMsg);
    })
);

getOldMessage(someUser).then(message => console.log(message));
```

Comment: hey i am trying this it is giving me error saying await is only valid in async function.

Comment: Anytime you use the `await` keyword it needs to be used in an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). You have two choices, wrap the await call to `getOldMessage` in an async function, or go the promise route (my second example).

Comment: @AkhilBisht If this answer is acceptable for you please select the checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I couldn't find the solution, so i solve it this way:

```
var oldMsg = {};
oldMsg = await messagedb.findOne({ "room": user.room });
console.log(oldMsg);
return oldMsg;
```

But, you must change your function to async.

Hope, that's help.

Comment: if you put `async` infront of `getOldMessage`, that function will return an promise instead of the value, so that wont work either